# Matching and merging two csv files in R

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have file 1 with attributes like (706 attributes)

```
Matchid TeamName    Opp_TeamName    TeamRank    Opp_TeamRank    Team_Top10RankingBatsman
1   New Zealand      Bangladesh       1             10                   2
2   New Zealand        India          1             2                    2
3   India             England         2             5                    1
4   Australia        England          6             5                    1
```

and file 2 with attributes  (706 attributes)

```
id  actual  predicted   error
3         79    206.828     127.828
1         90    182.522     92.522
2         101   193.486     92.486
4         89    174.889     85.889
```

I want to match "Matchid and id" of both files and add file2 attributes in file1 so that the final result is

```
Matchid TeamName    Opp_TeamName    TeamRank    Opp_TeamRank    Team_Top10RankingBatsman    id       actual  predicted   error
1   New Zealand      Bangladesh       1             10                   2                   1         90    182.522     92.522
2   New Zealand        India          1             2                    2                    2        101   193.486     92.486

3   India             England         2             5                    1                   3        79    206.828     127.828
4   Australia        England          6             5                    1                  4         89    174.889     85.889
```

so far I have tried tried simple `merge` function and it didn't work, how can I achieve my task?

Comment: `merge` should work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right). You can also use the `join` functions from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Why didn't `merge` work? Can you provide your code? If you're more familiar with SQL you can use `sqldf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge(file1,file2,by.x="Matchid",by.y="id")
```

Maybe this way?

Answer (score 0):

The dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)

joined <- inner_join(file_1, file_2, by = c("Matchid" = "id"))
```